# c reinterpret pointer to datatype with bigger size

Tags: c, casting, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to interpret WebSocket Frames that I get over a TCP connection. I want to do this in pure C (so no reinterpret_cast). The Format is specified in [IEEE RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5). I want to fill the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t flags;
    uint8_t opcode;
    uint8_t isMasked;
    uint64_t payloadLength;
    uint32_t maskingKey;
    char* payloadData;
} WSFrame;
```

with the following Function:

```
static void parseWsFrame(char *data, WSFrame *frame) {
    frame->flags = (*data) & FLAGS_MASK;
    frame->opcode = (*data) & OPCODE_MASK;
    //next byte
    data += 1;
    frame->isMasked = (*data) & IS_MASKED;
    frame->payloadLength = (*data) & PAYLOAD_MASK;

    //next byte
    data += 1;

    if (frame->payloadLength == 126) {
        frame->payloadLength = *((uint16_t *)data);
        data += 2;
    } else if (frame->payloadLength == 127) {
        frame->payloadLength = *((uint64_t *)data);
        data += 8;
    }

    if (frame->isMasked) {
        frame->maskingKey = *((uint32_t *)data);
        data += 4;
    }else{
        //still need to initialize it to shut up the compiler
        frame->maskingKey = 0;
    }
    frame->payloadData = data;
}
```

The code is for the ESP8266, so debugging is only possible with printfs to the serial console. Using this method, I discovered that the code crashes right after the `frame->maskingKey = *((uint32_t *)data);` and the first two ifs get skipped, so this is the first time I cast a pointer to another pointer.

The data is not `\0` terminated, but i get the size in the data received callback. In my test, I'm trying to send the message 'test' over the already established WebSocket, and the received data length is 10, so:

- 1 byte flags and opcode
- 1 byte masked and payload length
- 4 bytes masking key
- 4 bytes payload length

At the point the code crashes, I expect data to be offsetted by 2 bytes from the initial position, so it has enough data to read the following 4 bytes.

I did not code any C for a long time, so I expect only a small error in my code.

PS.: I've seen a lot code where they interpret the values byte-by-byte and shift the values, but I see no reason why this method should not work either.

Comment: It's hard to know for sure with the information you've presented, but it seems likely that the data pointer is not aligned properly for a 32 bit dereference. Try constructing the maskingKey one byte at a time. In all of your code, dereference data as a byte pointer. E.g. ((uint8_t*)data)[0]

Comment: The picture in the IEEE RFC 6455 reference shows that masking key is not aligned on a 32 bit boundary, so a miss-aligned access is likely causing the crash.

Comment: Your `payloadLength`, `maskingKey` and `payloadData` are not properly aligned within that structure. You can use `#pragma pack` on it, but then you will have to `memcpy` these variables into local copies before using them. Better yet, just redefine your protocol, and add `uint8_t reserved` right before those fields.

Comment: The lines at the start with `&` are a bit suspicious ,it's more common for values such as "opcode" and "length" to be LSB-based instead of keeping them at whichever bit position they were in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with casting a char* to a pointer to a larger type is that some architectures do not allow unaligned reads.

That is, for example, if you try to read a uint32_t through a pointer, then the value of the pointer itself has to be a multiple of 4.  Otherwise, on some architectures, you will get a bus fault (e.g. - signal, trap, exception, etc.) of some sort.

Because this data is coming in over TCP and the format of the stream / protocol is laid out without any padding, then you will likely need to read it out from the buffer into local variables byte by byte (e.g. - using memcpy) as appropriate.  For example:

```
if (frame->isMasked) {
    mempcy(&frame->maskingKey, data, 4);
    data += 4;
    // TODO: handle endianness: e.g.: frame->maskingKey = ntohl(frame->maskingKey);
}else{
    //still need to initialize it to shut up the compiler
    frame->maskingKey = 0;
}
```

Comment: well that sucks. I've of course heard about the alignment read faults nut never ran into any concrete problems. Thanks for this answer!

The ntohl don't seem to be in the c lib, so i use the method with single array reads and shifts

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems:

- `data` might not be correctly aligned for `uint32_t`
- The bytes in `data` might not be in the same order as your hardware uses for value representation of integer. (sometimes called "endianness issue").

To write reliable code, look at the message specification to see which order the bytes are coming in. If they are most-significant-byte first then the portable version of your code would be:

```
unsigned char *udata = (unsigned char *)data;
frame->maskingKey = udata[0] * 0x1000000ul
                  + udata[1] * 0x10000ul
                  + udata[2] * 0x100ul
                  + udata[3];
```

This might look like a handful at first, but you could make an inline function that takes a pointer as argument, and returns the `uint32_t`, which will keep your code readable.

Similar problem applies to your reads of `uint16_t`.